# Spark same aggregation on multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, average, multiple-columns

I want to get the average of all the columns in Spark dataframe. The following code does not return the expected result.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkExamples").getOrCreate()
columns = ["cell_id", "date_time", "tempreature", "pressure", "speed"]
data = [
    ("bvf_01", "1/01/2017 0:30", "205", "1046", "4070"),
    ("bvf_01", "1/01/2017 0:35", "20", "106", "470"),
    ("bvf_01", "1/01/2017 0:40", "220", "1046", "1070"),
    ("bvf_01", "1/01/2017 0:45", "205", "1046", "7070"),
    ("bvf_01", "1/01/2017 0:50", "209", "146", "4770"),
    ("bvf_01", "2/01/2017 0:30", "2560", "1046", "47400"),
    ("bvf_01", "2/01/2017 0:35", "2015", "10446", "40740"),
    ("bvf_01", "2/01/2017 0:40", "2015", "10426", "4070"),
    ("bvf_01", "2/01/2017 0:45", "215", "104266", "40670"),
    ("bvf_01", "2/01/2017 0:55", "2015", "1046", "4070"),
    ("bvf_01", "2/01/2017 0:30", "2205", "10466", "4070"),
    ("bvf_01", "2/01/2017 0:35", "2205", "10446", "45070"),
    ("bvf_01", "5/01/2017 0:30", "2560", "1046", "47400"),
    ("bvf_01", "5/01/2017 0:35", "2015", "10446", "40740"),
    ("bvf_01", "5/01/2017 0:40", "2015", "10426", "4070"),
    ("bvf_01", "5/01/2017 0:45", "215", "104266", "40670"),
    ("bvf_01", "5/01/2017 0:55", "2015", "1046", "4070"),
    ("bvf_01", "6/01/2017 0:30", "2205", "10466", "4070"),
    ("bvf_01", "6/01/2017 0:35", "2205", "10446", "45070"),
    ("mcv_02", "1/01/2017 0:30", "205", "1046", "4070"),
    ("mcv_02", "1/01/2017 0:35", "20", "106", "470"),
    ("mcv_02", "1/01/2017 0:40", "220", "1046", "1070"),
    ("mcv_02", "1/01/2017 0:45", "205", "1046", "7070"),
    ("mcv_02", "1/01/2017 0:50", "209", "146", "4770"),
    ("mcv_02", "2/01/2017 0:30", "2560", "106", "47"),
    ("mcv_02", "2/01/2017 0:35", "2025", "1046", "40"),
    ("mcv_02", "2/01/2017 0:40", "2415", "1045", "470"),
    ("mcv_02", "2/01/2017 0:45", "215", "104266", "4020"),
    ("mcv_02", "2/01/2017 0:55", "2815", "1046", "400"),
    ("mcv_02", "2/01/2017 0:30", "2205", "10566", "42070"),
    ("mcv_02", "2/01/2017 0:35", "2205", "10456", "45070"),
    ("mcv_02", "5/01/2017 0:30", "25650", "1046", "47400"),
    ("mcv_02", "5/01/2017 0:35", "2015", "15446", "40740"),
    ("mcv_02", "5/01/2017 0:40", "26015", "10425", "4070"),
    ("mcv_02", "5/01/2017 0:45", "2195", "104266", "40670"),
    ("mcv_02", "5/01/2017 0:55", "20815", "1046", "4070"),
    ("mcv_02", "6/01/2017 0:30", "27205", "10466", "4070"),
    ("mcv_02", "6/01/2017 0:35", "22405", "10446", "45070"),
    ("mfv_02", "2/01/2017 0:30", "2560", "106", "47"),
    ("mfv_02", "2/01/2017 0:35", "2025", "1046", "40"),
    ("mfv_02", "2/01/2017 0:40", "2415", "1045", "470"),
    ("mfv_02", "2/01/2017 0:45", "215", "104266", "4020"),
    ("mfv_02", "2/01/2017 0:55", "2815", "1046", "400"),
    ("mfv_02", "2/01/2017 0:30", "2205", "10566", "42070"),
    ("mfv_02", "2/01/2017 0:35", "2205", "10456", "45070"),
    ("mfv_02", "5/01/2017 0:30", "25650", "1046", "47400"),
    ("mfv_02", "5/01/2017 0:35", "2015", "15446", "40740"),
    ("mfv_02", "5/01/2017 0:40", "26015", "10425", "4070"),
    ("mfv_02", "5/01/2017 0:45", "2195", "104266", "40670"),
    ("mfv_02", "5/01/2017 0:55", "20815", "1046", "4070"),
    ("mfv_02", "6/01/2017 0:30", "27205", "10466", "4070"),
    ("mfv_02", "6/01/2017 0:35", "22405", "10446", "45070"),
]
course_df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
course_df.show()
data = df.withColumn("date_time", F.to_timestamp(df.date_time, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
exprs = [ftions.collect_list(colName) for colName in df.columns]
df10 = data.groupby("cell_id", "TimeStamp").agg(*exprs)
```

I want the result as a table like:

```
cell_id    date         ave_Tempreature   ave_pressure    ave_speed

bvf_01  1/01/2017
bvf_01  2/01/2017
bvf_01  3/01/2017
bvf_01  4/01/2017
bvf_01  5/01/2017
mcv_02  1/01/2017
mcv_02  2/01/2017
mcv_02  3/01/2017
mcv_02  4/01/2017
mcv_02  5/01/2017
mfv_02  1/01/2017
mfv_02  2/01/2017
mfv_02  3/01/2017
mfv_02  4/01/2017
mfv_02  5/01/2017
```

Comment: Why you use `collect_list` ? just use [`avg`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.avg).

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a window for this task. You can use `groupBy` and `avg`.

```py
date = F.split("date_time", " ")[0].alias("date")
df = course_df.groupBy("cell_id", date).agg(
    *[F.avg(c).alias(f"avg_{c}") for c in {"tempreature", "pressure", "speed"}]
)
df.show()
# +-------+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
# |cell_id|     date|   avg_tempreature|      avg_pressure|         avg_speed|
# +-------+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
# | bvf_01|5/01/2017|            1764.0|           25446.0|           27390.0|
# | bvf_01|2/01/2017|            1890.0| 21163.14285714286|26584.285714285714|
# | mcv_02|2/01/2017|2062.8571428571427|18361.571428571428| 13159.57142857143|
# | mcv_02|1/01/2017|             171.8|             678.0|            3490.0|
# | bvf_01|6/01/2017|            2205.0|           10456.0|           24570.0|
# | bvf_01|1/01/2017|             171.8|             678.0|            3490.0|
# | mcv_02|5/01/2017|           15338.0|           26445.8|           27390.0|
# | mfv_02|2/01/2017|2062.8571428571427|18361.571428571428| 13159.57142857143|
# | mfv_02|6/01/2017|           24805.0|           10456.0|           24570.0|
# | mfv_02|5/01/2017|           15338.0|           26445.8|           27390.0|
# | mcv_02|6/01/2017|           24805.0|           10456.0|           24570.0|
# +-------+---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Or this, if you don't want to list all the columns for calculating the average:

```py
date = F.split("date_time", " ")[0].alias("date")
df = course_df.groupBy("cell_id", date).agg(
    *[
        F.avg(c).alias(f"avg_{c}")
        for c in course_df.columns
        if c not in {"cell_id", "date_time"}
    ]
)
```

Comment: how about if i want to get the slop?